# Removing an element of linq chain

Tags: c#

Is is possible to convert linq like this:

```
context.Cars.Where(x => x.ProductionYear > 1991).Where(x => x.ModelName == "Porsche")
```

to

```
context.Cars.Where(x => x.ProductionYear > 1991)
```

Basically in this case I'd want to literally remove 2nd `Where` from this chain

I thought about converting it to an Expression tree and somehow rebuild it?

I've no idea

Comment: So you want to do this at runtime? I don't think it's possible and also would be some kind of a security issue.

Comment: @Compufreak Yea, dynamically

Comment: @Compufreak I mean we can dynamically extend LINQ Chains using delegates (func) like that ``foreach (var predicate in predicates_collection){ query = query.Where(predicate); }`` so I thought we could "rewrite" our query but while skipping X element.

Comment: The extension you show limits the number of results, whereas the other way around would increase the number of results. This would allow a method that got passed a limited amount of items to access more items than it was supposed to by the caller. That's why I think this might be a security issue, but maybe someone knows better and proves me wrong ;)

Comment: @Compufreak I do believe that when somebody has an access to your code and can edit it freely, then I think there's a worse sec issue :P Idk really, thats kind of difficult

Comment: I am talking about scenarios like a library providing functions returning IQueryables, it's just contradicting principles if you can modify the parent query. It would probably be better if you find a way to make your where-clause conditional, e.g. by using a configuration-object that can be modified and making the where like `.Where(!SearchConfig.ModelFilterIsEnabled || x.ModelName=="Porsche")`.

Comment: @Compufreak Not necesarily a security issue. If you can change the query arbitrarily though user input, it's a vulnerability, but if the user can only influence changes intended by the developer, it's normal working. Just in the same way that concatenating user supplied data directly is a problem (SQL injection) but concatenating hardcoded values chosen by the user is not (dynamic query building). Of course, a dynamic implementation may very well have unexpected side effect if one's not careful and anything dynamic generally is closer to a vulnerability than anything static.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to alter the Linq query at run time. I would create a criteria that user fills out to allow for model search **or** only production year.

Comment: *"I'd want to literally remove 2nd Where from this chain"* okay, then you do `context.Cars.Where(x => x.ProductionYear > 1991 && x.ModelName == "Porsche")`

Comment: Instead of removing one, what about a scenario where you combine the predicates you want at runtime and only include the ones you want? That way you're not removing any. You're just only including the ones you want.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes, I even wrote about it ``I mean we can dynamically extend LINQ Chains using delegates (func) like that foreach (var predicate in predicates_collection){ query = query.Where(predicate); } so I thought we could "rewrite" our query but while skipping X element. `` but what if instead of ``Where`` there's an e.g ``Select`` or ``OrderBy``?

Comment: That's the way to go, then. Instead of putting it together and trying to take it apart, just put it together using the pieces you want.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use function like this for retrieving data with different predictions using `IQueryable`, you only have to create your prediction depending on your rules in runtime.

```
public List<CurrentInventoryDetail> Get(TransactionServerDatabaseContext context, Expression<Func<CurrentInventoryDetail, bool>> predicate)
{
    return context.CurrentInventoryDetails.Where(predicate).ToList<CurrentInventoryDetail>();
}
```

You can use same idea but adopt it to meet your needs.